# How to initialize fields outside the constructor

Tags: android, class, kotlin, constructor

I have a data class that is used in Room. At the head of the class there are date fields in the form of a string _dateControl and _timeCreate. There are dateControl and timeCreate fields of type Long in the body of the class. When requesting data via Retrofit, the dateControl and timeCreate fields are initialized independently. But if I try to declare an instance of a class, then these fields(dateControl and timeCreate) are not initialized and equal to 0.

Class

```
@Entity
class DetailNum(
    @SerializedName("id_ndt_res")
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("id_pr")
    val idEntUser: Int,
    @SerializedName("id_parts")
    val type: Int,
    @SerializedName("dt_controlya")
    var _dateControl: String,
    @SerializedName("number_part")
    var numDetail: String?,
    @SerializedName("god_izg")
    var yearCreate: Int,
    @SerializedName("id_zavods")
    var idFactory: Int,
    @SerializedName("time_create")
    var _timeCreate: String,
    @SerializedName("id_result")
    var resultControl: Int,
    @SerializedName("familiya_i_o_speca")
    var fioSpec: String?,
    @SerializedName("is_new_part")
    var isNew: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_from_pto")
    var isFromPto: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_not_kriterii_01_08_2013")
    var isNotKrit01082013: Int,
    @SerializedName("isLoaded")
    var isLoaded: Int = 0

) {
    public fun getSimpleDateStr() = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Date(dateControl))

    val strResultControl: String
        get() = resultControl.toString()

    var dateControl: Long = 0
        set(value) {
            val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(_dateControl)
            field = date.time
        }

    var timeCreate: Long = 0
        set(value) {
            val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(_timeCreate)
            field = date.time
        }
    var nameResult:String?=""

    fun getFirstCharNameResult() = if(!nameResult.isNullOrEmpty()) nameResult?.get(0)?.toUpperCase() else ""
}
```

Try inicialize like this

```
var detailNum = DetailNum(0, 0, 0, DateUtils.getSimpleDateStr(Date()), "", 0, 0, DateUtils.getSimpleDateStr(Date()), 0,"", 0, 0, 0 )
```

Why are long date fields not initialized in the second case and how to initialize them? I am new in Kotlin, please explain, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields like `dateControl` and `timeCreate` are not initialised in the constructor! Their setter don't get called automatically if not by some framework.

If you want them to be set right after the constructor initialisation, you can either:

1) .. set default value immediately

```
val dateControl: Long = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(_dateControl).time
```

2) .. or use `init` if the operation needs more code or you want to gather inner field initialisations together

```
class DetailNum(...) {

   var dateControl: Long = 0

   init {
      dateControl = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(_dateControl).time
      ...
   }

}
```

More infoirmation about constructors and `init` you can find [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

BTW: your setters don't use the provided value at all, so actually they are useless.

Comment: In principle, everything is correct, but now if I do init{..} and remove the setter, when i get query from the Room, the dateControl is not initialized,it's initialized only then i do: var detailNum = DetailNum(...). Same thing with the first option(  1) .. set default value immediately )

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android and Room, but I guess that those fields outside of the constructor are also set by the library and override the default values. If this is the case, one solution would be to annotate those fields with `@Ignore` and make them initialized lazily with `val dateControl : Int by lazy { ... }`.

Comment: @VNprk You could also override the getters `get() = ...` which would always generate new and up-to-date values

Comment: I need var propertie, but lazy can only be used for val properties

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I realized my mistake, eventually made a complex getter and setter, without an init block

Answer (score 0):

use lateinit to the variables like below

```
lateinit var subject: TestSubject
```

Comment: I need Long type variables, but lateinit modifier is not allowed on primitive types

Comment: Yes, I forgot that only non-nullable non-primitive types may need lateinit to work around the type safety system.